# unix: merge 2 files using 2nd columns

Tags: unix, merge, awk

I'd like to merge two files according to the content of their 2nd columns.

File 1:

```
"4742"  "209220_at"     2.60700394801826
"104"   "209396_s_at"   2.60651442103297
"749"   "202409_at"     2.59424724783704
"4168"  "209875_s_at"   2.58773204877464
"3973"  "1431_at"       2.52832098784342
"1826"  "207201_s_at"   2.41685345240968
```

File2:

```
"653"   "1431_at"       2.14595534191867
"1109"  "207201_s_at"   2.13777517447307
"353"   "212531_at"     2.12706340284672
"381"   "206535_at"     2.11456707231618
"1846"  "204534_at"     2.10919474441178
```

To have in the end:

```
"3973"  "1431_at"       2.52832098784342 "653"   "1431_at"       2.14595534191867
"1826"  "207201_s_at"   2.41685345240968 "1109"  "207201_s_at"   2.13777517447307
```

I have tried `comm`, `diff`, some obscure `awk` one-liner without any success.
Any help much appreciated. 
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
  # store the first file, indexed by col2
  NR==FNR {f1[$2] = $0; next}
  # output only if file1 contains file2's col2
  ($2 in f1) {print f1[$2], $0}
' file1 file2
```

Comment: note that this will store the entire file1 in memory, so you might want to put the smaller file as `file1`

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with a combination of the `sort` and `join` commands.  The straightforward approach is

```
join -j2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)
```

but that displays slightly differently than you're looking for.  It just shows the common join field and then the remaining fields from each file

```
"1431_at" "3973" 2.52832098784342 "653" 2.14595534191867
"207201_s_at" "1826" 2.41685345240968 "1109" 2.13777517447307
```

If you need the format exactly as you showed, then you would need to tell `join` to output in that manner

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3 -j2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)
```

where `-o` accepts a list of `FILENUM.FIELDNUM` specifiers.

Note that the `<()` syntax I'm using isn't POSIX sh, so you should sort to a temporary file if you need POSIX sh syntax.

Comment: if you are using certain versions of bash, you can also write: `join -j2 <(sort -k2 file{1,2})`

Comment: Except that doesn't provide join with two distinct sets of input.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are small, write a program in a scripting language (Perl, Python and Ruby are all good choices) that reads the first into a hash whose keys are the second column, then read through the second file and use hash lookups to fin out what (if anything) can be joined.

If the files are large then for each file swap the first and second columns, pass them through the unix sort utility, and then in a scripting language merge (plus column reorder) the two sorted files.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0} NR>FNR && ($2 in a){ print $0,a[$2] } ' file2 file1
```